# Wordpress - Deep linking not functioning on homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, browser-history, deep-linking

I've been working on integrating deeplinking into a wordpress site im developing;
http://dhp.camoconnell.com/

the problem, it is working on sub pages but not the homepage. for example, this works

http://dhp.camoconnell.com/portfolio/snow/5

but this does not,

http://dhp.camoconnell.com/2

I'm using Modernizr to check for HTML5 history, and using jquery address as a fallback;

```
function initUrlHandler() {
    if(Modernizr.history) {
         if(window.location.hash != '') {
              changeUrl({}, window.location.hash.replace('#/', '/'));
         }

         window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
              onUrlChange(window.location.pathname);
         },true);
    } else {
         if(window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
              window.location.href = '/#'+window.location.pathname;
         }

         $.address.externalChange(function(event) {
              onUrlChange(event.value);
         });

         onUrlChange(window.location.hash);
    }


    if(firstUrlChange) {
        onUrlChange(document.location.pathname);
    }
}

function changeUrl(state,url) {
    if(Modernizr.history) {
         history.pushState(state, null, '/'+url);
    } else {
         window.location.hash = '/'+url;
    }
}

function onUrlChange(pathName) {
    var pathSplit = pathName.match(/(\d+)/);

    currentSlide = (pathSplit == NaN || pathSplit == undefined || pathSplit > options.slides.length) ? 0 : parseInt(pathSplit)-1;   


    if(firstUrlChange) {
         firstUrlChange = false;
         loadInitImages();
    }
```

The templates used on both examples are the same.. an `alert()` placed in the init func `initUrlHandler()` returns nothing, which lead me to think maybe the `.htaccess` file was interferring.

I've had a look at it, but havent managed to find a problem there.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

thanks for any help, really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
# wp base folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/?
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```